# Divergent results with Copy and Compare commands (RoboCopy Diff Du), please explain.

Tags: windows, command-line

With Windows 7 Professional 64 bit...

used a batch file and RoboCopy.exe to copy

4 files and 2 directories from
c:\temp  = SDD (Solid State Drive) to

r:\temp  = USB stick (flash drive) with command:

"C:\WINDOWS\system32\ROBOCOPY.EXE" "D:\TEMP" "R:\TEMP" /V /TEE /S /E /COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T /NP /XJ /R:1000000 /W:30 /LOG:r:\RoboCopyInfo.LOG

Question: 
Why does
diff.exe  see above copy command results via RoboCopy as Ok, no error, but,
  du.exe  to text files sees a difference?

"C:\Program Files\Gow\bin\DIFF.exe" -q -r "D:\TEMP" "R:\TEMP"

:: DIFF.exe  = diff (GNU diffutils) 2.8.7    https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/releases

:: -q        = Output only whether files differ.

:: -r        = Recursively compare any subdirectories found.

:: "D:\TEMP" = Source files on SDD (Solid State Drive).

:: "R:\TEMP" = Destination drive is HDD or USB stick (flash drive), replace R with appropriate Letter.

:: DIFF.exe    Exit status is 0 if inputs are the same, 1 if different, 2 if trouble.

But, du.exe  to text files sees above as different, batch file:

d:

cd\

cd temp

"C:\Program Files\Gow\bin\du.exe" -a -b -c -P -S -x  >r:\DU_d_TEMP.txt

r:

cd\

cd temp

"C:\Program Files\Gow\bin\du.exe" -a -b -c -P -S -x >r:\DU_r_TEMP.txt

:: du.exe    = Disk Usage (GNU coreutils) 5.3.0  https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/releases

:: "D:\TEMP" = Source files on SDD (Solid State Drive).

:: "R:\TEMP" = Destination drive is HDD or USB stick (flash drive), replace R with appropriate Letter.

:: -a        = write counts for all files, not just directories

:: -b        = bytes, equivalent to `--apparent-size --block-size=1'

:: -c        = total, produce a grand total

:: -P        = --no-dereference, don't follow any symbolic links (this is the default)

:: -S        = --separate-dirs,  do not include size of subdirectories

:: -x        = --one-file-system  skip directories on different file systems

---

DU_d_TEMP.txt

908 ./cicon9.gif

18855   ./Help/HTML/usage.htm

27047   ./Help/HTML

0   ./Help

297 ./OutPut 1 .log

52876   ./Q.EXE

58177   .

85224   total

---

DU_r_TEMP.txt

908 ./cicon9.gif

297 ./OutPut 1 .log

52876   ./Q.EXE

18855   ./Help/HTML/usage.htm

18855   ./Help/HTML

0   ./Help

54081   .

72936   total

---

du.exe text files sees a difference of

12288 bytes (85224 - 72936)

Question: 
Why does
diff.exe  see above copy command results via RoboCopy as Ok, no error, but,
  du.exe  to text files sees a difference?

--

Answer (score 0):

I kind of hesitate putting this as an answer, but it has a couple of possible explanations. I am not familiar with du or diff, but I assume diff compares files and reports differences, while du reports file and directory sizes for all files and dirs. Summary of files copied by looking at the du result files:

1. Four total files; 2 subdirectories plus the root directory (`.`)
2. Three files on root (`.`) totaling *54081* bytes. DU_d_TEMP.txt reports *58177* bytes, a difference of ***4096*** bytes.
3. No files directly in /Help dir
4. One file under /Help/HTML dir totaling *18855* bytes. However, DU_d_TEMP.txt reports *27047* bytes in /Help/HTML, a difference of ***8192*** bytes.

**Explanation 1**:
There are system/hidden files or junctions on D: that Robocopy either ignored or was unable to copy. Possibly on a different file system? (wondering why the **-x** flag was used on du)  This is **unlikely**, since Robocopy ignores most source file attributes when selecting files to copy. However, if it selected the file to copy, but was unable to, it's *possible* du and diff may ignore the system/hidden file itself, but du detected the space was used in that directory. Without knowing the complete setup, file system(s), connected drives/machines, etc. nor seeing the Robocopy log file, I can't rule it out yet. For example, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/460702) on the askubuntu forum regarding files on a Windows partition being able to be seen by Ubuntu but not by Windows.

**Explanation 2**:
The file system on D: stores files differently than the file system on R:. 4096 bytes is a common sector size on modern drives, so the two larger files (as opposed to the files under 1KB) on the root (`.`) and /Help/HTML/ directories may have an extra sector (*4096* bytes) or two (*8192* bytes) allocated to the file that is not used.

I'm not saying these are the only two explanations, but these are two *possible* explanations. If you still have it, posting the Robocopy log file *might* rule out Explanation 1.